# C++ Function receiving an enum as one of its parameters

Tags: c++, enums

I am trying to make a function receive an enum as one of its parameters. I had the enum as a global but for some reason my other files couldn't change the enum. so I was wondering how do you set an enum as an argument for a function like,

```
function(enum AnEnum eee);
```

or is there a better way to solve the above problem?

Okay a quick rephrasing of my question: I basically have numerous files and I want all of them to have access to my enum and be able to change the state of that enum also the majority of files that should be able to access it are in a class. The way I was attempting to fix this was by passing the enum into the function that needed to access it, I couldn't work out how to go about making a function receive an enum as one of its arguments.

Comment: Might be worth rephrasing, your question is not very clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "changing the enum"?

Comment: With "changing the enum", do you mean that you want to expand it, like, add new values?

Comment: i mean changing the value stored in it..not adding new values...i have no idea what that is called...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want to pass a variable that has a value of one of the enums values, this will do:

```
enum Ex{
  VAL_1 = 0,
  VAL_2,
  VAL_3
};

void foo(Ex e){
  switch(e){
  case VAL_1: ... break;
  case VAL_2: ... break;
  case VAL_3: ... break;
  }
}

int main(){
  foo(VAL_2);
}
```

If that's not what you mean, please clarify.

Comment: How can you access the next *enum* with this method? For example, using `foo(VAL_2+1);` for trying to access `VAL_3`?

Answer (score 1):

```
(1) my other files couldn't change the enum
```

You cannot change `enum` value as they are `constants`. I think you meant to change the `enum` variable value.

```
(2) how do you set an enum as an argument for a function ?
```

If you want to **change** the value of the `enum` variable then pass it by **reference**

```
void function (AnEnum &eee)
{
   eee = NEW_VALUE;
}
```

Comment: hmm yeah you have miss understood...sorry about the poor quality question i have edited it and i hope it makes more sense now

Comment: This answere is rather unstatisfying... why pass something by reference that seems to be global in the first place?